Section title centered, counter on the left
I would like to have my section titles centered, with the counter on the left, at the beginning of the line. The middle of the axis should coincide with the middle of the title, independently from the counter. So something that looks like this:
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ 1.1                    Section title                        │
│                                                             │
│ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.    │
│ Maecenas sed sapien et mauris hendrerit consectetur ac id   │
│ risus. Sed a lorem tincidunt, imperdiet lectus id, aliquam  │
│ turpis. Fusce eu arcu vel erat porttitor maximus at non     │
│ quam. In fermentum, tellus et commodo sagittis, tellus ante │
│ posuere mi, a pretium elit enim molestie arcu. Sed sed      │
│ magna nec felis viverra dictum eu auctor turpis. Quisque id │
│ dictum felis, non pharetra ex. In vel ligula at quam        │
│ efficitur consectetur sit amet eget ante. Duis non gravida  │
│ massa, vitae maximus odio.                                  │

Considering titles that would be longer than the line, this may be a nontrivial problem. However, there is no such situation in my case, so I don't really need that feature.
I've tried many variations of titlesec; none works so far.
Many thanks in advance.

Add \hfilneg before the section number (in a zero width box) and reinstate \hfil after it.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
 {\filcenter\bfseries}
 {\hfilneg\makebox[0pt][l]{\thesection}\hfil}
 {0pt}
 {}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

{\centering\smash{\vrule depth 2cm}\par}

\section*{Section title}

\section{Section title}

\lipsum[42]

\end{document}

The line before the first \section is just to mark the text block center.


That's fantastic. Thank you for solving my problem, and being so reactive.
